# Ability to choose your own "click" events in laser-controls?

Tags: aframe

Projects using the OculusGO or GearVR have a problem where the click event from laser-controls was triggered by BOTH the trackpad and trigger button click. Frustrating if you want different functionality for both (e.g. snap-turning on trackpad and click on trigger).

see line 74 (GearVR) and 79 (OculusGO) of https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/laser-controls.js

`cursor: {downEvents: ['trackpaddown', 'triggerdown'], upEvents: ['trackpadup', 'triggerup']},`

is there another way to do this or would it be worth having the option to select your own downEvents and upEvents in the laser-controls schema to forward to the various controller configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For snap turn you can listen to the button specific event instead of `click`:

```
controllerEl.addEventListener('trackpaddown', snapTurn);
```

You can also consider copying the `laser-controls` code to your `my-laser-controls` component and modify the downEvents array to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I could listen for the 'trackpaddown' but it will go up and call click also on release also correct?

And yeah copying is always an idea - I just try to avoid it unless necessary. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something else obvious here :)

Comment: FYI. I opened a [PR](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/3801) to trigger `click` events only on `trigger` presses, freeing the trackpad for other purposes

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was going to suggest something like this but wanted to make sure I understood your team's concept first.